C program alphabet order sort without using if-else and using only while loop do-while
I want my program to read the 5 input that is char and sort by alphabet order by using bubble sort.
Here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a, b, c, d, e;
    char temp;
    int cnt = 0;

    // Reading the characters
    scanf(" %c %c %c %c %c", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);

    // Convert characters to lowercase manually
    // We do not have a function, so we compare directly in the while loop

    // Using while loop to control the number of passes
    while (cnt < 4) {
        // Convert characters to lowercase in comparison
        // Comparison using ASCII values directly
        while (((a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z') ? (a + 32) : a) > ((b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z') ? (b + 32) : b)) {
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        while (((b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z') ? (b + 32) : b) > ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? (c + 32) : c)) {
            temp = b;
            b = c;
            c = temp;
        }
        while (((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? (c + 32) : c) > ((d >= 'A' && d <= 'Z') ? (d + 32) : d)) {
            temp = c;
            c = d;
            d = temp;
        }
        while (((d >= 'A' && d <= 'Z') ? (d + 32) : d) > ((e >= 'A' && e <= 'Z') ? (e + 32) : e)) {
            temp = d;
            d = e;
            e = temp;
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    // Printing the sorted characters
    printf("%c %c %c %c %c\n", a, b, c, d, e);

    return 0;
}


But I can't use the ?: operator. Is there any way to convert the lower case and uppercase without using if-else?
I figured it out using the && and * operators to convert it manually so if the condition is true(if char a is A-Z which is an uppercase character the result is 1*(a-A which is 32).
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a, b, c, d, e;
    char temp;
    int cnt = 0;

    // Reading the characters
    scanf(" %c %c %c %c %c", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);

    // Using do-while loop to control the number of passes
    do {
        // Convert characters to lowercase for comparison
        char a_lower = a + (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        char b_lower = b + (b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        char c_lower = c + (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        char d_lower = d + (d >= 'A' && d <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        char e_lower = e + (e >= 'A' && e <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        
        // Case-insensitive sorting
        while (a_lower > b_lower) {
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
            
            a_lower = a + (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
            b_lower = b + (b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        }
        while (b_lower > c_lower) {
            temp = b;
            b = c;
            c = temp;
            
            b_lower = b + (b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
            c_lower = c + (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        }
        while (c_lower > d_lower) {
            temp = c;
            c = d;
            d = temp;
            
            c_lower = c + (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
            d_lower = d + (d >= 'A' && d <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        }
        while (d_lower > e_lower) {
            temp = d;
            d = e;
            e = temp;
            
            d_lower = d + (d >= 'A' && d <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
            e_lower = e + (e >= 'A' && e <= 'Z') * ('a' - 'A');
        }
        
        // Increment the pass counter
        cnt++;
    } while (cnt < 4); // Repeat for enough passes to sort

    // Printing the sorted characters
    printf("%c %c %c %c %c\n", a, b, c, d, e);

    return 0;
}



How can you say i can't use the "?" when you already used it?

My bad my professor said not to use "?" or if-else on this assignment but I am just trying to convert the char is there another way to do it instead of using "?"

Do you need to print the originally entered character or may you print the converted upper case character instead?

Yeah, I do need to print the original character.

What does "// We do not have a function" mean? Are you allowed to use standard library functions (as you do with scanf, printf)?

That line is the character conversion function, but I manually convert it by adding 32 to the lowercase character. Since I don't have the function, I comment on it.

I know. I wonder if you are allowed to use toupper function or not.

I can't use the toupper function either.

And BTW: Your title mentions sorting but your question body only mentions converting to upper case. Is there a sorting issue as well?

The code you have does not answer your homework prompt. You should write a bubble sort to sort an array of char. The bubble sort should be in main(). Instead of a for loop, use a while loop. There is nothing in your HW prompt suggesting that you need to mess with toupper().

Thank you for your assistance. I believe I have resolved the issue. It seems that adding a break at the end of each while loop.

You need to go talk with your TA (or the professor) or another student in the class to get a better grasp on this. (You are starting out, and it is hard, but right now you are throwing random bananas at the problem.) Go get help.

Hey, I just figured it out. Thanks a lot for your help! Next time, I'll try asking my TA first.

Can you use max() and min() functions?

No, my professor wants me to use the basic knowledge from the textbook which is do-while while loop and the operator.

I'm confused because I can't use if-else. If I could use all the functions, this homework would be easy. :(

Can't you leave that course? Setting such tasks is nonsense, when you cannot use what all mindful programmers will use. Code golf is not for beginners, and rarely helps in professional programming. -- You can replace if-else by while(...)/while(!...)-break, but it is still nonsense.

Sorry, I can't because I'm currently in my junior year, and I honestly don't know what the point of this course is.

@johnnyrowdy If you can't use any functions other than those declared in stdio.h, I suggest looking for the functions you would use in the standard library if you were allowed and then implement them yourself.  You could also look at the generic sorting function qsort and implement your bubblesort using the same interface to make it capable of sorting arrays of any type. example

@johnnyrowdy are you allowed to use arrays? Anyway, please [edit] the question and tell us exactly what you are not allowed to use.

To perform the toupper() functionality without compares, use a table:
Like @Konstantin Makarov good answer but with wider character support (e.g. 0 ... 255) and not relying on ASCII.  ('A' to 'Z' do not need to be contiguous codes. e.g. Works with EBCDIC. )

char to_upper(char ch) {
  // Assign non-zero bits to flip for lower case letters.
  // The other 230 not explicitly initialized characters will get a zero for bits to flip. 
  static const unsigned char to_upper[UCHAR_MAX + 1] =
      { ['a'] = 'A' ^ 'a', ['b'] = 'B' ^ 'b', 
        /* 23 more */ ,    ['z'] = 'Z' ^ 'z'};

  unsigned char uch = (unsigned char) ch;
  return (char) (uch ^ to_upper[uch)]);
}


Note: a case-less sort ordering, done with ASCII, will sort '_' differently against letters depending on if letters are mapped to upper case than if letters are mapped to lower case as '_', and a few others, are between the upper and lower case letters.

You can compare without conditional operators in this way:
#include <stdio.h>

char chapmap[] =
    " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./"
    "0123456789:;<=>?@"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ{|}~";

char to_upper(char ch) {
    return chapmap[ch - ' '];
}

int main() {

    const int len = 5;
    char a[len];
    char temp;

    bool swapped;
    int i1;
    int i2;

    // Reading the characters
    scanf(" %c %c %c %c %c", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3], &a[4]);

    do {
        swapped = false;
        i1 = 0;
        i2 = 1;

        while (i2 < len) {

            while (to_upper(a[i1]) > to_upper(a[i2])) {
                temp = a[i1];
                a[i1] = a[i2];
                a[i2] = temp;
                swapped = true;
                break;
            }

            i1++;
            i2++;
        }

    } while (swapped);

    // Printing the sorted characters
    printf("%c %c %c %c %c\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]);

    return 0;
}

Input:
9 a 2 B =

Output:
2 9 = a B


If you want to do:
if (a > b) { swap_a_and_b }

without using if you can do:
// if (a > b) { swap_a_and_b }
int c = a > b;
a = a ^ c * b;
b = c * a ^ b;
a = a ^ c * b;

Such code can be "fun" but it's difficult to understand. Therefore it's best to avoid in real programs.

Notes: a = a ^ c * b; is like a = a ^ (c * b); due to  * has higher precedence than ^.  It is not like a = (a ^ c) * b;.  Could have used bool c = a > b; and achieved the same result.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Correct. And that's how it intended to be. So no problem

"So no problem" --> except we can improve on "it's difficult to understand.".  It would still be difficult, yet less difficult to understand with a = a ^ (c * b); b = (c * a) ^ b; a = a ^ (c * b);.  Relying on uncommonly used precedence rules (* vs. ^) makes code more difficult to understand.  It is a judgment call on the common-ness of (* vs. ^) , yet IMO, using () here is the better one.

@chux-ReinstateMonica To me your first comment indicates that something is wrong (which there isn't). If the comment only intended to address readability I missed the point. And readability is always opinion based. There are projects with coding guidelines that forbids unnecessary (...)
